# How to Gracefully Leave Project during a Sensitive Period?

Tags: job-change

I was thrilled when I was hired by this company at the beginning of the year, where I thought best practices and tools fitting my profile are the ones going to be used.

To my surprise, I came to realize that there are many fallacies in this project, especially in the most basic aspects.

I don't really like who I am working with nor what I am working with. It feels like everything is wrong in this project.

I was a go getter at the beginning, so this costed me to be burdened, whereas the reluctant peers are happy and wait to be baby-spooned peacefully.

My presence is critical, especially for the image with the client, but I am already gone, morally, but I need to be gone physically.

I can't resign right now because I need to find another job, and I need not to be on client's site (abroad).

Am I taking a big risk here if I attempt anything?

Comment: Please clarify: are you unable to find another job (in your home country) because you are abroad at client location, or you want to resign because they plan to send you to client location soon and you don't want to go?

Comment: @MaskedMan I can't find a job because I am abroad.

Comment: How much longer are you required to stay there? If you somehow managed to find a job in your home country, could you resign from abroad and make your trip back home in time for the new job? Your situation is a bit tricky to deal with but not impossible. However, there are a number of unknowns here which makes it difficult to give a proper answer.

Comment: At least another month. I am not sure I can find a job with my physical presence to interview(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resign without burning bridges when I'm a critical staff member?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56611/how-do-i-resign-without-burning-bridges-when-im-a-critical-staff-member)

Comment: Financially, I can afford to be unemployed. But it's hard where I live to find a job when being unemployed (suspiciousness).

Comment: @JakeGould question updated. No ego involved here, I have exchanged a few emails and now my absence has been very much noticed. Most partners told me not to leave so that I won't embarrass my employer.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same in one project.

My team was about 7 members and I was one of the two crucial members in my team. We both were suffering with the team dumbacity and fed up with spoon-feeding to them all the time. I almost felt like I was working as a freelancer for that project.

I informed how I was feeling about the team and project challenges and was little afraid it could put a negative impression on my attitude.

But thank to our Principal Consultant, who understood our situation and helped increasing the facilities and breaking down the work individually among the team. This has reduced a lot of burden. The best part in that was our salary got hiked and we got better team from next project.

So, don't feel tensed/abandoned when in such situations, coz your work will show what you are capable of. Always inform your situation to your team leader/Project Manager/Principal Consultant.

All the Best!

Answer (score 2):

Considering this is a matter of weeks and not years, my suggestion is bite the bullet on this one and finish the project first and then leave. Everyone in their career faces a situation where they are on a project they do not enjoy at all. While it is always important to enjoy what you do, these phases are true judge of your character, patience and commitment.

Make sure your team manager knows how uncomfortable you are but do ensure your commitment instead of the demoralizing reasons. This gesture will go a long way with your employer and with your client and may actually help you in getting a new role after this.

Also, I do not think difficulty in getting a new job should make you stay at your current job. Irrespective of how easy or tough it is for you to get a new job, if this is critical time for your current employer and if they are counting on you, you should own up the responsibility on your shoulders and see this project through.

Time will fly soon and when you look back me how would you want to remember this time? The time when saw through a critical project in spite of the hurdles of the time when you escaped with the first opportunity you got!

Having said this,I understand this is after all a corporate job and not a call of duty in war! So everything is not about honor and commitment but your own satisfaction and career. My point is just that if it is short term, do it anyways!