# Is it a good idea to ask for a company to lay you off

Tags: professionalism

Heres the situation, Im in a small early stage startup and the role that I was hired for is turning out to be much different than what I had imagined, so this is a strong point of contention for me and really not the role that I had wanted. Add ontop of this that I don't see eye to with a co-founder of the company, and they no longer want to talk to me about certain business decisions at the company, but I keep getting roped into them by the CEO who does realize that this co-founder doesn't understand this particular field.

Heres my question: Is it a good idea to have a sit down with all the co-founders/managers of the company and have a conversation about the situation and have them either resolve it, or simply as them to lay me off and stop wasting their money and my time here.

Comment: Asking to be laid off doesn't make much sense, as resigning is usually seen as better than getting laid off or fired by future employers. If you want to leave, just [find another job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/why-shouldnt-i-resign-when-i-havent-secured-another-job) and then [resign](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56611/how-do-i-resign-without-burning-bridges-when-im-a-critical-staff-member).

Comment: Why do you want to complicate your life? If you don't like the job, just find another job and resign. Not sure what you hope to gain by having a sitdown and asking them to lay you off.

Comment: I don't really know what "asking to be laid off" means.  If this is software related, at the time of writing (2018) you can get a new job in five minutes.  If you don't like the job, just politely tell them you're leaving, leave, and get another job.

Comment: @Fattie being Laid Off (though technically a lay off is not the same as redundancy)  or made redundant implies a pay off its about the $$

Comment: I get what you're saying @Neuromancer .  If - amazingly - OP could get the company to give money to OP, **OP should do that straight away**.

Comment: Is the company offering voluntary redundancies or something? By "lay off", are you expecting some sort of redundancy payment? Because otherwise I don't see why you don't just resign, but if you are expecting them to pay you to leave, why would they? If you're not performing to a good standard they'd be within their rights to fire you, if you are, why would they lay you off? But if you can get them to pay you to leave, go for it! But I think if you were that good a negotiator you wouldn't be on here asking about it...

Answer (score 2):

You ask two questions:

- should you sit down and try to solve the situation with your managers

Yes, this is a good idea. Be open and positive about it.

- Should you ask your company to lay you down

No, it's generally not a good idea.

In most legislation there is a difference between resigning and being laid off, in terms of access to benefits. For those I am aware of, being laid off entitles the worker to access social benefits such as unemployment subsidy, while this is not the case for resignation. 
And when interviewing for another job it is a different story having to explain a lay off or a resignation.

Also for the company it can made a difference reporting workers have been laid off or resigned. Again, in my experience certain public funding or tax exemptions are not accessible to companies with a high lay off rate.

Under this premises, you asking your company to lay you off sounds like a you are asking them to play the bad guys while you look like the good guy. Some may even take it as an insult to their intelligence and knowledge.

Comment: I think this answer addresses only the part of the question about leaving the company. That is an important part but personally I think the part about solving the problem within the company should be the first priority.

Comment: @Edgar, I looked over the first part of the question. Now I edited my answer

Comment: @L.Dutch In some countries, you can get an agreement between both parties to end the contract. It was a common practice in France, for example, for a worker drop his performance and force being laid off for social benefits. That is why there is a mutual agreement possibility now.

Comment: This answer contradicts its self its better to be made redundant than resigning for mainly financial reasons

Comment: @Neuromancer, I don't see the contradiction. I agree that it is better to be made redundant than to resign, but why should the company take this burden in this specific case? it's the employer who is not "liking" the work environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good idea to talk to all of them and look for a solution.

I suggest you prepare yourself that you can argue why the current situation is not good for you and not good for them.

And think about arguments they might bring up why they do what they do.

And then I suggest you go open minded in such a meeting. Maybe you will find a way to solve the problem with you working there permanently, maybe it makes sense that you work for them only as a consultant, or maybe it's best if you go separate ways.

I think it does not make sense to stay in a company in a position you don't like. Solve it or move on. And if you need the money and it is difficult for you to find a new job then think twice about what might happen. Maybe you have to look for a new job before you bring up that issue in a meeting.