# Afraid to leave my first job

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development

I'm facing the following problem:

I started software development internship year and a half ago, I've passed the internship and now I'm full time software developer.
The thing is my company has zero development over the past year and a half, my company lost a lot of projects and employees. My career got stuck, I'm not developing my professional skills or anything else because I have almost no work to do.
I have very low salary and I want to change my job (not only because of low salary, but because I want to chase my career). I'm feeling guilty to quit my job, because my boss gave me a chance with the internship when I really needed it.

I've been to few interviews and got very good offers, but I'm feeling afraid/anxious about telling my boss that I would like to leave.

How can I overcome this fear and sense of obligation (resulting from being given a chance by my boss)?

Comment: Leave.  But I also YTC as career choice is off topic.

Comment: Related: [How do I resign without burning bridges when I'm a critical staff member?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/56611) and [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149)

Comment: You can be friends with your boss, but your relationship remains one of business. They pay you money, you do your job. That's as far as it needs to go. You're doing yourself no favours by stagnating. Ask yourself this: if he needed to fire you, would he feel bad because you gave them a chance by ignoring all the other good offers? I don't think so. Your relationship is one of business. Do what's best for you.

Comment: I once had a boss say that the best compliment they can get is to have an employee leave to do something better. It means they did something right in your development. Sounds like you have offers to do something better. Your boss will understand.

Comment: "Kind of afraid to tell my boss that I want to quit" - if he has any sense at all, he is expecting your resignation, especially given the fact that there Is no development work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to change my job...
>
> I'm feeling guilty to quit my job...
>
> I've been to few interviews and got very good offers...
>
> Kind of afraid to tell my boss that I want to quit.

Don't feel guilty. Don't be afraid.

Your first resignation will be difficult. But we all go through it and it's never as bad as you might imagine.

Your boss will understand. These things happen.

Comment: and even if the boss does not understand, where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm feeling guilty to quit my job, because my boss gave me a chance with the internship when I really needed it.

Your boss didn't do it for the sake of helping you. They needed workforce, you gave them workforce in exchange of salary. Neither of the two sides was receiving without giving.

> My career got stuck, I'm not developing my professional skills or anything else because I have almost no work to do.

That's a more than legitimate reason to be looking at other opportunities.

> Kind of afraid to tell my boss that I want to quit.

See above, you gave them something and in return you got something. If you don't want to burn bridges, acknowledge the positive things of your experience there, express your gratitude and make clear that for you is now time to take the next step.

If your boss will express regret for your departure, take it as a sign you have done a good job. No sane boss would like to have non motivated employees. And, if the roles where reversed, they would put no tears in terminating your contract. So, don't feel too bad. If you don't care about your life and career, nobody will do.

Good luck!