# Loved my work place now I kinda Hate it - Is it time to leave? Would it hurt my carrer if I stay?

Tags: career-development, career-switch, morale, south-america

To start I work in a multinational company which owns a bunch of other small companies in such a way they only serve one purpose, like IT. I started as a Trainee on the corporate finance department, and then got a period contract and then an actual contract. I worked helping a consultant team by loading data and ensuring that it was right by checking some websites(time-consuming). I'm a little obsessive and worked flaws by hand up to $ 0,001 USD. Now we have like 120 bank accounts I have the exact cash position for all of them, every day in a couple of hours.

The software went up for a successful trial period, the consultant team was out and my trainee period finish by being contracted. The first time they tried to implement the software it failed like a year before me and my old boss got into this company.

As time went by, more and more companies needed to be added and I was way faster than the consultants so they assigned me that job, besides my other tasks. The IT company was so full of bureaucracy and bad disposition that they weren't an option. So I dusted off my coding skills and started doing some pretty neat macros on VBA that would help me with data checking and also learned Python in a couple of months to create some web scrapers just to help me out. Made the jobs of a day into a couple of hours.

Then word spread and people started to want my "apps", an automation tool. One upper-manager from other area looked for my knowledge to make automation that free a time consuming(really dumb) task for 3 teams, one of those teams was my team and I consider myself a team player. My boss, a middle-manager, said ok to this and even asked for a desktop(computer are really hard to come by in this company) with the specs I wanted, so it would be reliable.

I deliver in 2 weeks, two implementations and one need add-on that I did to influence some people into lending me some time of their own. You give me something I give you something kind of deal.

The CTO from the internal IT company freaked out because no one can code outside his company. He was 2 month in into his position, they have no coders(hard to believe I know) and no one sent a memo. I got audited, got into a dispute with the security officer about it. The project stalled for months.

One day, this bottom-manager from the IT company comes by my seat and asked me to a conference room. We chat on good terms and he told me the one solution for the trouble I made was to go to his team or otherwise he will have to look for providers and start a project and so on. I told him that I just happen to get my degree in "Business Mayor with an Economics Minor" and also got my MBA.

Then the next day this guy from HR comes to my seat and started talking that I was crazy for what I was asking, he disclosed loudly how much many I wanted, with people staring and hearing. He is a loud person and always tells inappropriate stuff, so I believe people didn't think too much out of it but me it was really humiliating. I have been feeling dread since then(about 6 months) and started hating my job.

Since then we moved to a new floor, I was seated with another team far away from my actual team, stopped including me on meetings, stopped disclosing information and started asking me about matters about said information, has less work and projects. I have been forbidden by the CTO, which is from a different company from which I'm contracted, to code.

The IT company tried to take over my tasks but a whole team failed. It was a disaster, so they gave it back to me.

I spoke with my boss about me and my career, and told me he would speak to management about 1 month ago. I have been checking with him weekly but he didn't have time, because he had to travel to another country to work. When the software is not up and running, my boss and all of the team can't get stuff done because they don't have the time. Pays get delayed, interest is charged in the bank accounts as there was not the money they thought it was there, etc.

I feel like my boss and the team needs me, but I also feel like I should leave this place for good and look for a new job.

**I'd like to know how to leave in good terms and not to burn bridges, Is that possible at all?**

Please I know it's a lot of text and also English is not my native language so be kind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resign without burning bridges when I'm a critical staff member?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56611/how-do-i-resign-without-burning-bridges-when-im-a-critical-staff-member)

Comment: Your question title and your bolded question in the post ask two different questions. Since the one in your post is the one you've gotten two answers for, that's the one I suggested a dupe target against.

Comment: This question "will it hurt my career if I stay?" asks us to make a prediction of the future, but no one knows the future. Maybe it will, maybe it will not; the only way to find out is to try, and you don't get to know what would have happened if you did the opposite. **Questions about unknowable futures are off-topic on this site; we are not fortune-tellers**.

Answer (score 11):

You asked,

> I'd like know how to leave in good terms and not to burn bridges, Is that possible at all?

Yes, it is possible. Just find a new job, get the contract, give your notice, and go work for your new employer. People do it all the time - you won't be burning any bridges unless you go out of your way to cause trouble. Make sure you understand if there is a notice period specified in your current contract, and respect it. Continue working as hard as you normally would while you look for your new job, and don't tell your current employer anything until you have your new job secured in writing.

As you're looking, keep in mind the lessons you're learning at your current employer and try to be selective about where you go, so you don't end up in a similar situation. Use the interview process as an opportunity to learn about your prospective employers.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like know how to leave in good terms and not to burn bridges, Is that possible at all?

Yes- Just leave the company and follow their procedures for leaving (2 week notice for most jobs in the US, not sure about standard procedure for South America).

Throughout the body of your post you somehow feel like your in debt to the company simply because they offered you a job and you were excited to accept. Things were going well- until they didn't- and you no longer want to work there. This is perfectly normal and sounds like a good reason to change jobs. You won't be burning any bridges unless you do something malicious in your final days.

Your boss and team will find a replacement- as hard as it might be to swallow, your company does not need you and was functioning fine before you got hired. They will remain functional after you leave and even if they didn't- it wouldn't be your fault. Your job isn't to make sure the company and your team is fine even after you leave.

Stop worrying and do what's best for you, not your company.